# has_many with :readyonly and :uniq in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Working with a 3.2 application being updated to 4.2 and the `has_many` has multiple qualifiers and I'm not sure of the right way to frame them in a 4.2 env

This was the original

```
has_many :students,  through: :student_enrollments, readonly: true, uniq: true
```

This works -- but its missing readonly

```
has_many :students, -> { distinct }, through: :student_enrollments
```

I tried

```
has_many :students, -> { distinct, readonly }, through: :student_enrollments
```

But that failed. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do, where you need to chain the two methods:

`has_many :students, -> { distinct.readonly }, through: :student_enrollments`